# Excluir um selector css

Tags: html5, css3

Eu tenho o seguinte:

```
        <div>
            <ul class="menu-top-header-main-right">
                <li><span class="icon-procurar"></span></li>
                <li>Entrar</li>
                <li>Inscrever-se</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

e meu css:

```
.top-header-main header div ul li span{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .8em;
    width: 20px;
    height:24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.top-header-main header div ul li:not(.icon-procurar):hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2BDE73;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Pretendo excluir o `span` do `:hover` mas parece que não funciona.

Alguma ajuda? Obrigado.

Comment: Defina melhor o que seria "excluir o span do hover".

Comment: Quando você fala excluir, você não está querendo dizer por exemplo que quer atribuir a propriedade 'display:none;' ao elemento, fazendo assim ele "sumir" da tela.

Comment: Como podem observar no código, o span encontra-se dentro do li, logo, ao aplicar o :hover, o span também pega os atributos que estão definidos no :hover, mas eu gostaria que o span não tivesse por se tratar apenas de uma imagem

Answer (score -2):

**PARENT SELECTOR**

O que você está tentando fazer chama-se *parent selector* que é um tipo de seletor que **NÃO** existe em CSS, nem em CSS3. Explicando um pouco melhor, você quer estilizar um elemento de acordo com a presença/ausência de um elemento filho. Como já dito não pode ser alcançado com CSS3, mas pode com jQuery:

```js
$('li:has(span)').css("borderBottom", "none");
```

```css
div ul li span{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .8em;
    width: 20px;
    height:24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div ul li:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2BDE73;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="menu-top-header-main-right">
    <li><span class="icon-procurar"></span></li>
    <li>Entrar</li>
    <li>Inscrever-se</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Algumas fontes de conulta (em inglês):

[CSS selector for “foo that contains bar”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000582/css-selector-for-foo-that-contains-bar)

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Estás a dizer que o :not não existe em css3?

Comment: @CélioGarcia o :not existe sim no `CSS 3` talvez ele tenha tentado explicar alguma outra coisa.

Comment: Eu penso que sim... porque eu sei que o :not existe, já o fiz antes mas na forma em que estou a tentar fazer agora, é que não funciona!

Comment: @CélioGarcia :not é uma PSEUDO classe e não PARENT SELECTOR